# Activity logs using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do an activity log wherein it saves the time when you logged in an account. The problem is the id saves the value while action saves "0" and datetime saves "0000-00-00 00:00:00" in the database. What's the problem with the code?

```
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
            $time = date('m/d/y h:iA', time());

            $log = 'logged in';
            $sql = "INSERT INTO logs VALUES (
                    id = '1',
                    action='has logged in',
                    datetime=now()
                    )
                ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO logs (id,action,`datetime`) VALUES ('1','has logged in',now())
```